# How to DISTINCT in INNER JOIN in mysql?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, distinct

I want to distinct `root_master.rootName` but I don't know how to perform this action. Any suggestion how can I get distinct result of `root_master.rootName`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dispatch_master.dispatch_id,
    dispatch_master.root_id,
    dispatch_master.dispatch_quantity,
    dispatch_master.returned_quantity,
    dispatch_master.disposed_quantity,
    dispatch_master.date,
    root_master.rootName
FROM dispatch_master
INNER JOIN root_master
    ON dispatch_master.root_id = root_master.r_id
    AND dispatch_master.root_id != '1'
    AND dispatch_master.date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

OUTPUT: [output for this innerjoin](https://drive.google.com/open?id=118ouIAn2OTrOjVpqimCq7kOsX3cbAXCD)

Comment: hi! May I know the output of your code? it seems to me that the problem is the joins.

Comment: Please include sample input and output.

Comment: yea sure i will

Comment: `select distinct` operates across the entire row so that each row is different to every other row - somewhere/anywhere in the row. It **does not stop repetition of a value down a column**. So if this is what you are asking for I suggest you do this AFTER you have used SQL (e.g. in PHP)

Comment: thanks for your response i will do like you said

Comment: @sam for each rootName which row you want from dispatch_master table ? Its obvious if there are several rows for  rootName you will get all results linked to that rootName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ##dispatch_master.dispatch_id  <<< remove this
      dispatch_master.root_id
    , dispatch_master.dispatch_quantity
    , dispatch_master.returned_quantity
    , dispatch_master.disposed_quantity
    , dispatch_master.date
    , root_master.rootName
FROM dispatch_master
INNER JOIN root_master
    ON dispatch_master.root_id = root_master.r_id
    AND dispatch_master.root_id != '1'
    AND dispatch_master.date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

For every column you include you INCREASE the probability of MORE distinct rows. Conversely, reduce the columns can also reduce the number of distinct rows.